# windows phone 7 Navigate Uri

Tags: windows-phone-7

in my **MainPage.xaml's constructor**, I do some controls and want to navigate to Home page in some conditions like that:

```
  NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Home.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

But I take **NullReferenceException** above the code line. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the navigation service is not setup correctly when the constructor is called. Try moving your navigate code to the OnNavigatedTo() method.